# How to perform indexing and slicing for sparse tensor

Tags: pytorch, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to access elements of the sparse coo tensor.

```
i = [[0,2]]
v = [np.array([1,2,3,4]),[5,6,7,8]]
a = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(i,v,(4,4))
print(a.to_dense())
tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

But I'm unable to acces neither one element, neither the whole row

```
print(a[0])
RuntimeError: sparse tensors do not have strides
print(a[0,:])
RuntimeError: sparse tensors do not have strides
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: I don't about the torch version, but in `scipy.sparce` the `coo` format doesn't support indexing.  The `csr` and `lil` formats do.  Have you studied the docs?

Comment: Even in `scipy.sparse`, indexing is quite a bit slower than with dense arrays.